# Not able to perform operations inside a docker container

Tags: docker

I have a simple flask docker cotainer. 
However not able to perform any operation inside it like `ls` etc.

```
$   docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
    19411ea239fa        xapo-app            "python api.py"     About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   jolly_banach
```

Finally I had to break it.

```
$ docker exec -t 19411ea239fa /bin/bash
root@19411ea239fa:/app/SampleRESTApi# ls
^C
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `-i` flag, to make the `exec` session interactive:

```
docker exec -ti 19411ea239fa /bin/bash
```